# Hadoop master: nice: /bin/yarn: No such file or directory

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

Hadoop 2.4.1 setup was working fine, i wanted to use yarn framework so i updated the config files as below:

yarn-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs</name>
    <value>/var/hadoop/yarn</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
    <value>master:8031</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    <final>true</final>
</property>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
</property>
```

yarn-env.sh

```
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
export YARN_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
```

NodeManager logs are not logged in the default location as previously but in a separate location `/logs` and the first line shows

```
nice: /bin/yarn: No such file or directory
```

What Hadoop is trying to do is that the /bin/yarn is what it's assuming to be present but it's not there.

Comment: Could you please explain more?

Comment: i have put all the information i know is there anything specific you are looking for?

Comment: @Raghuveer did you find the solution?

Comment: @RaviMCA : create the folders as it expects is what i can think of now.